# multiline in textview not working with sppannable text

Tags: android, textview

I am using `TextView` to display text. I need to display max 3 line of text. To accomplish this , i have used `maxLines` property.

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textFeedText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFeedDate"
                android:textSize="@dimen/d13sp"/>
```

Now i need to set sppannable text in textview. Following is my code to set clickable span.

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(requiredString);
        ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAppBlue));
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };

        spannableString.setSpan(clickSpan, indexOfStart, indexOfEnd - 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.append(spannableString);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It display okay. Now when i tap on textview then sometimes multiline property not seems working. Textview text scrolls vertically. And display following view.

[image]

Anyone has faced such issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Share your requiredString.

Comment: It is normal string shown in blue color here. i.e. 'Anna' , 'Comment:..'